ProxMox VM doesn't have any network
I have an ProxMox and I been trying for 4 days to fix a debian VM on it having no internet, I have 4 additional IPv6 and I been trying to setup a VM with one but it doesn't seem to have any networking
When I use "ping google.com" I get "network unreachable
When I ping google IPV6 adress I get "address not reachable" and when I ping the VM IPv6 adress I get 100% packet loss, please help

God help you. And if you want us to help, you have to provide technical information, we're not mind readers.
